# Can´t load a tomcat 5.5 application to production, and can´t find any errors

Tags: spring, tomcat, quartz-scheduler

i have a server with a bunch of tomcat, springs applications, and i can´t load a particular one that uses quartz. The main problem is that i can´t find an error anywhere that tells me what went wrong. And the same application runs fine in the test server, which uses de samde 1.6 jdk, tomcat 5.5. The only difference is that the productions server is in debian lenny, the test server in Centos. I only get a HTTP Status 404: requested resource not available.

Nothing usefull in catalina.out, configured log4j using this tutorial: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/logging.html , but can´t find any error there either. So i was wondering where can i get a hint of the problem ? tomcat starts succesfully and the other applications load without any problem.

Thank you very much

Comment: Does this particular application successful starts?

Answer (score 0):

tail -f the catalina.out when you load the application, even it fails you still should able to see the output of tomcat trying to load the classes.

You might want to adjust to log level to info to see that tho.

*with 404 error, you could also try check the apache log, if you are using mod jk or proxy linking them.